# Microsoft Word 2007 text location

Tags: microsoft-word

Word 2003 displayed the text location (eg: `2.3"`) on the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to enable this in Word 2007?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Microsoft Word 2010, but if I recall correctly, it should be the same:

1. **Right-click** the **Status Bar** at the bottom of the window.
2. Now, in the **Customize Status Bar** menu, enable **Vertical Page Position**.

Comment: It's the same in 2007. :)